# How do I know if selling equity is better or not in this problem?

Tags: interest, equity, cost-basis

In this exemplar situation, how do I know if selling my equity is better nor?

Situation: I have a small business which I am a 50% owner of. The business is currently worth $6,000,000 and is making $750,000 per year. Now that the business is established, I want to buy a property for my own personal use, but I need to raise $700,000 to buy the property. My bank manager says they are willing to lend that amount in interest only basis (as long as the interest is being paid, the $700,000 does not have to be paid back), for an annual interest rate of 6.0%. In this case, I am not sure if paying interest would be a better economical decision instead of just selling a portion of my equity.

How can I calculate/quantify the cost associated with both the options?

Comment: Taxes would come into play here, so jurisdiction matters.

Answer (score 2):

Your equity is currently earning 12.5% per year (750k/6M = 0.125) so it is earning more than your debt would cost. I assume that this property is not earning anything since it's "for personal use", so it would be better (mathematically) to keep an asset earning 12.5% instead of using it to save on 6% debt.

That assumes that the business is stable and will *continue* to earn 750k going forward, but you have a decent amount of cushion (your profit would need to be cut in half to make it an even comparison)

You should also consider the ramifications of having less than 50% in terms of control of the business.

That said, having an interest-only loan, even for real estate, is incredibly risky. I would see if they can do a traditional mortgage for a lower fixed rate. Most of your mortgage payment will be interest in the first few years anyway, so it shouldn't be a huge impact on cash flow (if it *is*, then you're probably over-extending anyway). That way, you can pay down some of the principal as you go and reduce the risk that you get underwater in the loan (and reduce your interest cost along the way). Plus you can pay down the loan even *faster* if you have good cash flow years.

Comment: Some follow up questions to the response: 1. why did you represent the yearly earnings in a form of % of the equity? 2. Is your interpretation of "annual interest rate of 6.0%" that the loan amount will be 6% of the equity I have? I am just not sure how I should be interpreting the annual interest rate in this scenario.

Comment: If you cashed out 700k of equity to purchase the property, you'd be "paying" (meaning you'll get less of the profits) 12.5% of that each year, versus paying 6% of that in interest on a loan. There could be lots of variables given that equity is not guaranteed income, you don't directly get all earnings, etc. but that's the rough comparison.

Comment: The OP should look at the after tax interest rate of the loan because it might not be 6%. Likewise, the after tax yield on the equity. Lastly, if the property loses 100k dollars in market value, his net worth changes by 100k dollars. I wouldn't be concerned about having a negative equity position, that is being "underwater", on the property.